# How to export mysql database from phpmyadmin with where clause?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Actually I am just wondering if there is any features in phpmyadmin to allow me to selectively export database based on where condition? Thanks a lot.

Comment: yes, just  run the query, then all the way at the bottom of the screen there is a 'export selection' link. click that link and you'll be taken to the export page with the selected data. There you can also choose to generate the sql for the table structure.

Comment: I have to export a table at one time by this way. I need to export databases with hundreds of tables very often. So if I have to export a table at one time, you can image that it would be very inconvenient for me. So I am just wondering if there is a feature in phpmyadmin to achieve my goal or can you recommend a more powerful mysql administration tool? I already tried workbench, phpmyadmin and adminer. None of them suits my need well. Thank you very much!

Comment: The most powerful tool would be command line. Every serious admin should try to know how to do it with just a console. MySQL workbench is also a nice tool, but command line is it.

Comment: I almost forgot command line. I think you are right. If you like, you can post your last comment as an answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The most powerful tool would be command line. Every serious admin should try to know how to do it with just a console. MySQL workbench is also a nice tool, but command line is it